# Finding 'representative' group of data in database

Tags: python, sql, oracle, algorithm

I have these data in database which looks more or less like this:

`id (int) not null unique | measurement_id (int) not null | range_id (int) not null unique | temperature (int) | TimeOfDay (string) either Dawn or Day or Night | Weather.Clear (Boolean) either true or null | Weather.Cloudy (Boolean) either true or null | Weather.Fog (Boolean) either true or null | Weather.Snow (Boolean) either true or null | Area.City (Boolean) either true ot null | Area.Country (Boolean) either true or null | etc`

there are hundreds of thousands of rows of this and let's say that someone did statistics on these data and for exampe 40% of all rows have Day in (TimeOfDay (string) either Dawn or Day or Night) column, 65% is true in (Weather.Clear (Boolean) either true or null) column etc. Additionally usual logic apply so if Weather.Clear is set to true then Weather.Cloudy is null etc.

My job is to find 'representative' group of let's say a 1000 rows of data. So I need 40% out of 1000 = 400 rows which have Day in (TimeOfDay (string) either Dawn or Day or Night) column, 65% (650) of them have 'true' in (Weather.Clear (Boolean) either true or null) column etc.

I realize that it will be very dificult to achieve using SQL (oracle) queries only (or maybe I am wrong), so what kind of approach should I use here with general purpose programming language like python to obtain results that I need? Are there any algorythms for this?

Regards.

Comment: simplify your scenario for sake of understanding. Give sample data for few rows and expected output based on that.

Comment: Oracle provides statistical functions. Have a look at [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-foundation/or-statistical-functions-overview-130361.pdf) and [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/index-092760.html)

Comment: Oracle doesn't have `boolean` datatype, so how are those values represented?

Comment: @Utsav sample in case it allows for better understanding the problem:
[example data][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfo9q.png
of course statictics were done on column like:
<code>temperature | TimeOfDay | Weather.Clear | Weather.Cloudy | Weather.Fog | Weather.Snow | Area.City | Area.Country</code>

Comment: You say "of course" but there's nothing of course about this, It's not a normal database table. Presumably it's a file loaded without much transformation in the ETL process.

Answer (score 1):

One approach used in statistics to get a *'Representative' group of data* is [random sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample).

The simples possible impelementation in SQL  is as follows

1) assign each row in your table a random value between 0 and 1

2) sort the data on the random column

3) get the first N row in the defined order

```
SELECT id
FROM
  (SELECT id,
    rnd
  FROM
    ( SELECT id, dbms_random.value rnd FROM t
    )
  ORDER BY rnd
  )
WHERE rownum <= 1000;
```

Comment: `ORDER BY dbms_random.value` would work and it's less typing,

Comment: @APC I deliberately typed a bit more to keep the code in sync with the description above:). But of course in practical use your shortcut will be used!

Comment: Without knowing more about the use case, and without a defined thresholds for "representativeness" I think a randomized subset should be good enough.